# Realurl : CSS are not loaded also realurl appends the page path

Tags: typo3, realurl

I am using real-url (1.11.2) , typo3 4.6. I got a problem in FE URL.

i got URL like

```
http://{domain-name}/page1/page2/
http://{domain-name}/page1/page2/page3/
```

URL should be

```
http://{domain-name}/page1
http://{domain-name}/page1
```

How to achieve this.

Also i lost my CSS and JS reference.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your config.baseURL, like:

`config.baseURL = http://www.example.com/`

(In your root template of the website)

Comment: I know the answer is super old but for anyone finding this looking for the answer: Don't use `config.baseURL` anymore. Instead use: `config.absRefPrefix = /` or `config.absRefPrefix = http://www.example.com/` allthought the first one works obviously better with multidomains.